# Only-Quote page after abstract page?

Tags: header-footer, quoting

I want a quote-page after my abstract in my document. No numbering, no header, just the plain quote plus source. Howto?

My main file (the file is named 'slogan' in here):

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    bibtotoc,
    cleardoubleempty,
    idxtotoc,
    ngerman,
    openright
    final,
    listof=nochaptergap,
    ]{scrbook}

\input{src/settings}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\include{src/title}
\cleardoubleemptypage

\frontmatter

% Abstract
\include{src/abstract}
\cleardoubleemptypage

\include{src/slogan}
\cleardoubleemptypage

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of contents}
\cleardoubleemptypage

% ...
```

The slogan file, by now:

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    \begin{quote}
        % quote
    \end{quote}
\end{center}
\vfill
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. How do I add a citation source, without using bibtex and the whole thing around it? Just a note directly under the citation?

Comment: Forget the source thing. I can do it on my own. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

To obtain what you want, you can simply add the line

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

at the beginning of `slogan.tex`.

The page style `empty` adds no headers and footers to the page. The command `\thispagestyle` ensures that the change will be made locally to the page where it has been issued.